# Running cocos2d with iPhone SDK 4 GM

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios4

I tried to build my (cocos2d 0.99.0-based) project with iPhone SDK 4 GM which was just released today. The reason is because I want to incorporate iAds in my apps. However I got 20 error messages which looks like errors in library calling. Can anyone tell me whether we can actually use cocos2d 0.99.0? I'm aware that 99.3 was released but they didn't mention any iOS 4 compatibilities.

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't clear. Here are the error messages:

```
    Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FingerRide-1.app/FingerRide-1 normal i386
cd "/Users/monkey/Current/iPhone whatnots/FingerRide-1"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk "-L/Users/monkey/Current/iPhone whatnots/FingerRide-1/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" "-F/Users/monkey/Current/iPhone whatnots/FingerRide-1/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist "/Users/monkey/Current/iPhone whatnots/FingerRide-1/build/FingerRide-1.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FingerRide-1.build/Objects-normal/i386/FingerRide-1.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -all_load -ObjC -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -lz -framework AVFoundation "-lcocos2d libraries" -o "/Users/monkey/Current/iPhone whatnots/FingerRide-1/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FingerRide-1.app/FingerRide-1"

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZAttributeRun", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-ZAttributeRun in libcocos2d libraries.a(FontLabelStringDrawing.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableArray in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCFileUtils.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSObject", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_CDataScanner in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDataScanner.o)
      .objc_class_name_CJSONDeserializer in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONDeserializer.o)
      .objc_class_name_CJSONSerializer in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
      .objc_class_name_ZAttributeRun in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
      .objc_class_name_ZAttributedString in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
      .objc_class_name_CCConfiguration in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCConfiguration.o)
      .objc_class_name_CCFileUtils in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCFileUtils.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSString", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDataScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libcocos2d libraries.a(NSCharacterSet_Extensions.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCConfiguration.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSString in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCFileUtils.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSException", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDataScanner_Extensions.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libcocos2d libraries.a(NSScanner_Extensions.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSException in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableString", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableString in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableString in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSArray", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSArray in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSDictionary", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDictionary in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDictionary in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSDictionary in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSAssertionHandler", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSAssertionHandler in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSAssertionHandler in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCConfiguration.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCFileUtils", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-CCFileUtils in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCBitmapFontAtlas.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CCFileUtils in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCSpriteFrameCache.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CCFileUtils in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCTextureCache.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CCFileUtils in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCTileMapAtlas.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CCFileUtils in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCTMXXMLParser.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZAttributedString", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_ZAttributedString_$_ZAttributedStringDrawing in libcocos2d libraries.a(FontLabelStringDrawing.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-ZAttributedString in libcocos2d libraries.a(FontLabelStringDrawing.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CJSONDeserializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-CJSONDeserializer in libcocos2d libraries.a(CLScoreServerRequest.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSError", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSError in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONDeserializer.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSError in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSMutableDictionary", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableDictionary in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSMutableDictionary in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSCharacterSet", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSCharacterSet in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDataScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSCharacterSet in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDataScanner_Extensions.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSCharacterSet in libcocos2d libraries.a(NSCharacterSet_Extensions.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSCharacterSet in libcocos2d libraries.a(NSScanner_Extensions.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-CCConfiguration in libcocos2d libraries.a(FontManager.o)
      objc-class-ref-to-CCConfiguration in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCTexture2D.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSBundle", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSBundle in libcocos2d libraries.a(CCConfiguration.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSData", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSData in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDataScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSData in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSNumber", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libcocos2d libraries.a(CDataScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNumber in libcocos2d libraries.a(ZAttributedString.o)
  ".objc_class_name_NSNull", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONScanner.o)
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@NSNull in libcocos2d libraries.a(CJSONSerializer.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What are the error messages? Perhaps it's telling you that you must make an appointment to meet the magical fairy that does the compiling? How are we supposed to know?

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear jer. I've added the error messages. They're all in cocos2d libraries.

Comment: having this issue with another library with iOS4 GM seed. Did you find any solutions? Doing a clean build is not helping.

Comment: All I really did was update my cocos2d (to 0.99.3) and did a clean build. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks, a clean fixed it for me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what people are telling me and my own experiments, a clean build can fix the problem. Maybe you can try to update cocos2d as well.

Comment: I just had this problem after downloading cocos2d 99.4 and the clean and build fixed it.  Curiously, the box2d and chipmunk projects didn't need the clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

this may be a shot in the dark...but it's hurt me before. try removing the space from your "iphone whatnot" directory

Comment: ah.. okay, that might work. But I actually fixed it by cleaning up the project and rebuilding it. This is one of those moments when I'm not sure if I'm dumb or smart...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing some frameworks in your project, like Foundation or CoreFoundation.